# Rails 3 respond_with custom template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `latest` action in my controller. This action just grabs the last record and renders the `show` template.

```
class PicturesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json, :xml

  def latest
    @picture = Picture.last

    respond_with @picture, template: 'pictures/show'
  end
end
```

Is there a cleaner way to supply template? Seems redundant to have to supply the `pictures/` portion for the HTML format since this is the Sites controller.

Answer (score 7):

If the template you want to render, belongs to the same controller, you can write it just like this:

```
class PicturesController < ApplicationController
  def latest
    @picture = Picture.last

    render :show
  end
end
```

It is not necessary the pictures/ path. You can go deeper here: [Layouts and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

If you need to preserve xml and json formats, you can do:

```
class PicturesController < ApplicationController
  def latest
    @picture = Picture.last

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {render :show}
      format.json {render json: @picture}
      format.xml {render xml: @picture}
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: **This is the correct answer.** One Gotcha worth noting: calling `render 'show'` *only renders the show template*, it does not call the show action. So, if there are instance variables in your `show` action that the show template needs, you have to also set those in your `latest` action, or any other action that renders the `show` template.

Comment: See my updates. I need to preserve "API navigation" for this action (JSON and XML formats). I know I can give `respond_with` a block and do `format.html { render :show }`. This also seems not as clean as it should be though.

Comment: How do you do it for a custom template, not one that is already part of the rest actions? How about for a custom template in a shared folder?

Comment: @gwho You can use `render 'shared/file_name'`. Please read the link about Layouts and Rendering I left on my original answer.

Answer (score 6):

I've done this similarly to @Dario Barrionuevo, but I needed to preserve XML & JSON formats and wasn't happy with doing a `respond_to` block, since I'm trying to use the `respond_with` responders. Turns out you can do this.

```
class PicturesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json, :xml

  def latest
    @picture = Picture.last

    respond_with(@picture) do |format|
      format.html { render :show }
    end
  end
end
```

The default behavior will run as desired for JSON & XML. You only have to specify the one behavior you need to override (the HTML response) instead of all three.

[Source is here](http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/8/6/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-cleaner-restful-controllers-w-respond_with).